# How to install the latest Java OpenJDK version?

Tags: 10.04, java, openjdk

My system is Ubuntu 10.04.4 (LTS)

I know there is OpenJDK "1.6.0_24"

The version in Ubuntu is "1.6.0_20"

How do I install the latest version of the OpenJDK available?

Comment: no idea why ... possibly because you had commentary in your question.  I've tidied this for you.

Comment: These are different, JDK6 and JDK7 are not compatible and both have "latest" versions. Like Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: @HristoHristov Not completely true. Java 7 is fully backwards compatible with Java 6; anything that works on 6, also works on 7.

Comment: @Jesper This would mean that Java6 should not exist anymore. Then why the latest linux distros still come with 6? I am not sure it is full backwards compatible.

Comment: @HristoHristov Companies are always very careful to jump onto a new version of anything. If their software works with Java 6 and they don't have a good business reason to go to 7, they stay at 6. And Oracle will continue to support 6 for a while. Upgrading doesn't happen immediately everywhere the day a new version comes out.

Comment: @HristoHristov With regard to Java, formerly Sun and now Oracle have always been extremely careful to ensure backwards compatibility. It's not like Python 3 which has clear incompatible changes compared to Python 2.

Answer (score -1):

I Just used this line in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Hope it work for you.

Comment: I'm guessing this has been voted down because OpenJDK 7 is only available from the package repositories in Oneiric (11.10) and later.

Comment: And because JDK 6 and 7 are different things with different "latest" versions. And 10.04 comes with JDK 6.